# Using local emulator for firebase with expo

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

I am trying to firebase to emulate locally for testing a react native app I am working on with expo. To that end I am trying to set the host of the functions and firestore to the proper port on local host.

After many iterations I finally found a weird combination of imports and calls that did not error. However, when I tried to run it with expo my App came up as a blank screen with no errors.
I am pretty lost at this point and the firebase documentation is confusing.

This is my current index.js:

```
import firebase from "firebase"
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/functions';
import 'firebase/app';


const config = {
    //config info
  };
const fb = firebase.initializeApp(config);
const firestore = firebase.firestore();
const functions = firebase.functions();

if(__DEV__){
  firestore.settings({
    host : "localhost:9000",
    ssl : false
  });
  functions.useFunctionsEmulator("http://localhost:5001");
}
const auth = fb.auth();

export { auth, functions, firestore }
```

The imports are very weird and I don't understand them but I got them from another stack overflow thread and it was the only thing that made it even get to the end of the file. Is there something very obvious I am missing about setting up the local emulator?

Answer (score 2):

the issue you may be having with using the Local Emulator Suite and Expo together is that that "localhost" refers to the device you're using. If you're testing on a physical device, you need to point Firebase to the running instance on your computer. I wrote up a short explainer on it here:

https://dev.to/haydenbleasel/using-the-firebase-local-emulator-with-expo-s-managed-workflow-5g5k

Comment: Unfortunately the article is no longer available

Answer (score 1):

[This article](https://dev.to/haydenbleasel/using-the-firebase-local-emulator-with-expo-s-managed-workflow-5g5k) does a good job of showing you how to get the right debugger host IP dynamically (if you're running Expo Go on a mobile phone).

basically, it all comes down to:

```js
const origin = Constants.manifest.debuggerHost?.split(":").shift() || "localhost";

firebase.auth().useEmulator(`http://${origin}:9099/`);
firebase.firestore().useEmulator(origin, 8080);
firebase.functions().useEmulator(origin, 5001);
```

Comment: It’s worth noting that this is the same article referenced in @haydenbleasel’s from last year—and, in fact, the article is by the author of that post.

Comment: Unfortunately the article is no longer available

Comment: In case it helps, [here's the most recent archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20221208143116/https://dev.to/haydenbleasel/using-the-firebase-local-emulator-with-expo-s-managed-workflow-5g5k).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work on my machine via:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import '@firebase/firestore';
import '@firebase/functions';

const firebaseConfig = { /* config data */ }
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.firestore().settings({ host: "localhost:8080", ssl: false });
firebase.functions().useFunctionsEmulator('http://localhost:5001');
```

In your attempt, I think your problem might be the the way you declared:

`const fb = firebase.initializeApp(config);`

and then forgot to use the initialized `fb` -- and instead you used `firebase` again.

try changing these lines:

```
const firestore = firebase.firestore();
const functions = firebase.functions();
```

to this:

```
const firestore = fb.firestore();
const functions = fb.functions();
```

or just use the `firebase` class directly instead of setting to a variable.

---

**Edit**:

I noticed that I actually had my firestore store `host` value set incorrectly so I edited it above - I had added `http://` to the beginning but that's not what you want for that parameter.

Note - If you want to see exactly what your dev env is doing when trying to connect to your local firestore, add this line:
`firebase.firestore.setLogLevel('debug');`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure it's your only problem. But for firebase functions to work in an emulator using your android or iphone you need to change

functions.useFunctionsEmulator("http://localhost:5001") to
firebase.functions().useFunctionsEmulator("http://10.0.2.2:5001");

it's for an android emulator only. It's the IP adress of the device you need to reach.

Answer (score 0):

Current answers didn't help for React Native + Firebase Emulators.

Changing the host based on `Platform.OS` fixed it for me, based on https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_auth#instrumentauth

```js
if (__DEV__) {
  const origin = Platform.OS === 'android' ? `10.0.2.2` : 'localhost';
  const authUrl = `http://${origin}:${firebaseConfig.emulators.auth.port}`;
  console.log(`Connecting local auth emulator`, authUrl);
  connectAuthEmulator(auth, authUrl);
}
```